# Latex: How to remove the word "appendix" in list of tables (because appendix is overwriting the name of the table)

Tags: appendices, thesis, overleaf

I have a problem with my list of tables on latex. My appendix tables appear like "Table APPENDIX A.1 nameoftable". But here, there is a problem because the word APPENDIX A.1 is overwriting the name of the table.

Here is where i write appendix in my .tex (after this i wrote my tables):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{shorthands=off}{babel}    
\documentclass[12pt,oneandhalf,chaparabic,ie,phd,eng,oneside,pntc]{gsufbe}

\makeatletter
\if@rmnchp
  \def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\else
  \def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabto}


\makeatletter
\let\old@includegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][,]{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{\old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd9>\textwidth
    \old@includegraphics[#1,width=\textwidth]{#2}%
  \else
    \old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\author{JOHN DOE}
\title{The Influence of Probabilistic Methodologies on Networking}
\trtitle{Ağ üzerinde Olasılık Yöntemlerinin Etkisi}

\date{October 2014}

\supervisor[prof]{JOHN DOE}
\departmentofsupervisor{Industrial Engineering Department, X}

\committeememberi[assistprof]{JAMES DOE}
\affiliationi{Industrial Engineering Department, X}
\committeememberii[assistprof]{JESSICA DOE}
\affiliationii{Industrial Engineering Department, University of Kentucky}
\committeememberiii[assocprof]{RICK DOE}
\affiliationiii{Computer Engineering Department, MIT}
% Fourth committee member
\committeememberiv[assocprof]{MAN DOE}
\affiliationiv{Computer Engineering Department, MIT}

\keywords{STEEVE}

\abstract{}

\acknowledgments{}

\setlength{\jot}{20pt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\begin{document}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.5cm}
% Preliminaries
\newlength\myindent
\setlength\myindent{6em}
\newcommand\bindent{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\myindent}
  \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{\myindent}
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup}

\newtheorem{thm}{Definition}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{thm}}
\newtheorem{prp}{Proposition}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theprp}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{prp}}
\newenvironment{prf}{\noindent{\bf Proof}}{$\hfill \Box$ \vspace{10pt}}

\chapter{Introduction}

\bibliography{thesis_references}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\appendix

\chapter[A]{}
In Tables~\ref{tab:A1}, \ref{tab:A2}, \ref{tab:A3}, \ref{tab:A4}, \ref{tab:A5}, \ref{tab:A6}, \ref{tab:A7}, each cell shows the f1-score performance of a specific feature-set with a specific classifier in a specific case, using a specific sensor.

\begin{table*}[h]
\centering
\caption{Scenario 1: f1-scores considering all cases}
\label{tab:A1}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
Interarrival Times & $\gamma=10$ & $\gamma=1$ & $\gamma=0.1$ \\
\specialrule{2pt}{1pt}{1pt}
$x_1$   &   6.9530  &   7.0078  &   7.0940  \\
$x_2$   &   6.9870  &   7.0144  &   7.0760  \\
$x_3$   &   6.9860  &   7.0344  &   7.0820  \\
$x_4$   &   7.0000  &   7.0267  &   7.0900  \\
$x_5$   &   6.9900  &   7.0222  &   7.0920  \\
$x_6$   &   6.9800  &   7.0211  &   7.0910  \\
$x_7$   &   6.9990  &   7.0211  &   7.0800  \\
$x_8$   &   7.0000  &   7.0167  &   7.0900  \\
$x_9$   &   7.0130  &   7.0044  &   7.0870  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}

\input{vita.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

[image: The problem in list of tables (the word "appendix a.1 a.2 a.3" etc.)]
[image: alternative link to the possibility of not seeing the image above]

I need to do one of them: Removing the word "APPENDIX" from list of tables or putting the name of table after APPENDIX A.1.

All latex files (.cls, .def, .bib, etc.) can be easily downloaded from this link: *http://fbe.gsu.edu.tr/tr/belgeler/tez-yazimi* under the name **Tez Yazım Şablonu(Latex)**

I don't know how to do this. How can I fix it? 
I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: I can't click on the link https://i.hizliresim.com/NnqdAP.png; I am forbidden.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Your MWE is not quite minimal (not sure we need all the definitions of `includegraphics` and all the packages and so on... It is also not quite working, the cls file calls .def files we do not have, your code calls a bibliography style we don't have a .bst for, and you have a bibliography file that is not included... Please help us help you by providing something we can work with :)

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay , i added an alternative link for image.

Comment: @EladDen thank you for your comments. I've added all necessary file links to my message.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the class file gsufbe.cls. I can't find that class file by a web search. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay you can download class file gsufbe.cls from here (in the zip file): http://fbe.gsu.edu.tr/tr/belgeler/tez-yazimi under the name Tez Yazım Şablonu(Latex) or if you want to download only .cls file, i uploaded it here: https://ufile.io/avr7x

Comment: I can help a little, but to properly fix the class file, you should either talk to the person who wrote it and explain the problems you are having, or ask permission to use a more standard class file. There are many excellent class files from many different universities, which you could easily alter just a little (changing the university name, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your tex file, before `\begin{document}`, add the lines:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thetable{%
    \ifappendix%
        \Alph{chapter}%
    \else%
        \if@rmnchp \Roman{chapter}%
        \else\vspace*{10pt} \arabic{chapter}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
.\@arabic\c@table%
}
\newif\ifappendix
\def\appendix{\selectlanguage{English} \cleardoublepage \par
    \global\appendixtrue
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{0.5cm}
    \selectlanguage{English}
\def\@chapapp{APPENDIX}
\def\thechapter{   \MakeUppercase \appendixname \hskip 12pt \Alph{chapter}}}
\makeatother
```

This will only fix the problem with the tables having APPENDIX in their names, and get the word APPENDIX out from the names of the appendices and the names of the tables:

[image: List of tables]

It won't fix the figures or illustrations (which need a similar solution). Most importantly, it won't fix the error in the table of contents entry for Appendix A, which I haven't understood yet:

[image: table of contents]

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my most important problem. I noticed another problem "APPENDICES" is missing (it should be above Appendix A) in the table of contents.

Comment: @SmA: There is a line commented out in your class file which would add APPENDICES to the table of contents above Appendix A. Again you should probably talk to the person who wrote the class file, because it was clearly a deliberate decision to remove APPENDICES from the table of contents, and it might be some strange requirement of your university.

Comment: Ah okay, i saw that. You're right, thank you again.

Comment: I have tried your script but it causes another problem in my pdf file. This part: `\def\thetable{%
    \ifappendix%
        \Alph{chapter}%
    \else%
        \if@rmnchp \Roman{chapter}%
        \else\vspace*{10pt} \arabic{chapter}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
.\@arabic\c@table%
}` Each time when I use \ref{} to reference a table, I obtain approximately half-line space just below the line I'm using it. For example, if I use two \ref{} in tex file. This space is doubling on pdf. And when I delete it, the old problem comes back.

Comment: @SmA: I don't get the same problem. Could you write a minimal example file and post it in your question? Please make certain it causes the problem, and that no smaller file causes the same problem.